# <iframe> isn't visible in chrome/safari/edge

Tags: iframe

OK i'm having some issue with my iframes on [mykiajovan.com](http://www.mykiajovan.com) I have a soundcloud player at the top on the site and a youtube video in the middle, but they will not show up. Im using standard responsive markup for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ah, Desktop and Mobile differ significantly. :)

Looks fine to me. The youtube video appears below the rest of the content on my phone.

[image: Screenshot from iOS Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

I added the position: absolute to the iframe and it showed up, with position: absolute i couldnt seem to get the iframe to center (using margin: 0 auto and then align="center") so i made them full width.